# Documenting browser support

Tags: legal, browser-support

Are there any good articles or standards for documenting browser support for a web application? We test in IE 7+ and develop in IE 9/10+, as well as chrome, and would like to come up some good legal verbage to describe supported browsers for our product.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to state browser support in "legal" terms. Most sites add something like:

> Tested using the following browsers: [Browser icons](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/) (with version numbers)

Alternatively, you could include screenshots with different browsers to demonstrate this, or provide a link to results from an online screenshot service like this one:  [Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/)

Comment: The web component is part of a suite of tools that is about to have a new release published and we are under some pressure to have the web component covered by our system requirement details as far as browser support. We do not have the resources to do full testing for any other browsers. But since we have done thorough testing in IE and used chrome to develop it, we were looking for something along the line of "verified in IE7+ and webkit browsers" or something like that. Thanks for the Browser Shots link btw.... thats pretty neat.

Comment: No problem. I think I follow what you mean...I don't think there's a standard way of stating which browsers are supported. Most sites just use browser icons (like I linked to), and state underneath the minimum browser version number with a `+`. Or as you wrote, you can just state "Tested in IE 7+" too. I would take a look at some of the jQuery plugins since they're designed to be cross-browser compatible. For example: http://html5box.com/html5gallery/index.php
BTW, another helpful site for browser testing is: https://saucelabs.com/
(since Adobe BrowserLab closed)